# Passing structure pointer to functions

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to understand a piece of code. 
I have a structure and I create a struct variable globally and I pass the address of the struct variable created to different functions. 
in REC_createInstance I assign value of oil_qty as 5. 
in REC_testInstance I am trying to read the value of oil_qty
eg)
In this case it works. when a structure variable is created.
and the values assigned to the variables of the structure inside the function are retained through the program.

```
t_REC_instance instance;
void main()
{
REC_createInstance(&instance);
REC_testInstance(&instance);
}
```

But in the below code when a structure pointer is created and I pass it to the function I cannot read the value of oil_qty in REC_testInstance that was assigned in REC_createInstance.

```
t_REC_instance *instance;   //  structure pointer is created

void main()
{
REC_createInstance(instance);
REC_testInstance(instance);
}
```

```
int REC_createInstance(t_REC_instance* instance)
{


    instance = malloc(sizeof(t_REC_instance));  //code needed when structure pointer is created

    instance->currentRecipe =REC_Alloc();
    if (!instance->currentRecipe)
        {
        return -5;
            //BEF_EHJ_LOG(-5, destroy_ctx);
        }
        instance->currentRecipe->tAppBread.oil_qty=5;

    return 0;
    destroy_ctx:
    return -5;
}


int REC_testInstance(t_REC_instance* instance)
{


    int var=instance->currentRecipe->tAppBread.oil_qty;


}
```

What is happening when a structure pointer is created? why I cannot read the value of oil.qty assigned 
in REC_createInstance in  other function? Thanks for sharing knowledge.

Comment: `t_REC_instance *instance;` Is an uninitialized pointer that points to nowhere. That's why you need `malloc`. To make it point to valid memory. [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](//stackoverflow.com/q/562303)

Comment: `void f(int x) {x=7;} int main() {int i=5; f(i); printf("%d\n", i);}` <- don't compile this but tell me what number you think it prints

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Actually a pointer variable at global scope will initially have a null pointer value. Still bad news, yes.

Comment: @user253751 : It should print 5 , so it means that memory allocated in REC_createInstance is local only to that function. If I want to pass the instance to other functions then it should be available in the main. so a function that returns the address of the instance that is created , something like this t_REC_instance *REC_createInstance() should make the instance available for other functions.

Answer (score 1):

In `REC_createInstance` you're modifying `instance` which is a parameter to the function.  Changing a parameter isn't reflected in the calling function.

You need to pass in the address of the variable you want to modify, and dereference accordingly inside of the function.

So your function would look like this:

```
int REC_createInstance(t_REC_instance **instance)
{
    *instance = malloc(sizeof(t_REC_instance)); 
    (*instance)->currentRecipe =REC_Alloc();
    ...
```

And you call it like this:

```
REC_createInstance(&instance);
```